# 3D graphing using latex with complex equation

Tags: equations, 3d

i am new to 3D graphing using latex, is that anyone here can do a 3D graphing for this complex equation below?

```
\left[
    \left(
    \frac{x^2}{7^2}\right)
    \cdot
    \sqrt{\frac{\lvert\lvert x \rvert-3\rvert}
        {\lvert x \rvert -3}}
    +\left(\frac{y^2}{3^2}\right)
    \cdot
    \sqrt
    \frac{\lvert y+ \frac{3\sqrt 33}{7}\rvert}
    {y+\frac{3\sqrt 33}{7}}
    \right]-1
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This not an equation – only an expression – so what is there to graph?

Comment: Do you mean `z=f(x,y)`, where `f` is as in the expression?

Answer (score 1):

Like the commenters above I am not sure how to interpret this question. Possibly you mean this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] {(x*x/(7*7))
    *sqrt(abs((abs(x)-3)/(abs(x)-3)))
    +(y*y/(3*3))
    *sqrt(abs(abs(y+(3*sqrt(33)))/7))
    *(y+(3*sqrt(33))/7)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I merely converted LaTeX code to some expression that pgf can understand, and as you see the rules are rather simple. I also made sure that the argument of the square root cannot become negative, something that might not be necessary for certain plot domains but you did not specify a domain. If you have one in mind, you can add `domain=<xmin>:<xmax>,domain y=<ymin>:<ymax>` to the options of the plot.